# Finding the hardware based MAC address and ignore other devices that have MAC addresses

Tags: visual-studio-2010

From Visual Studio how can you find the MAC address of the Ethernet or wireless card and ignore VPN virtual mac address and other devices that may have MAC address that show up when you look at ipconig - all   We need to find just the MAC address that is providing the internet connection.

Comment: What if there are multiple Ethernet adapters?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking several questions here.

---

The first question is: "How do I determine which network adapter is providing the connection to the Internet?"

The answer to that question is: "Consult the [routing table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779122.aspx)." Also, ["How does Windows 7 decide which route to take if 2 connections to an internet source exist? (e.g. a Wireless and an Ethernet one to a router)"](https://superuser.com/q/198544/101823)

The [`GetBestInterace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365920.aspx) function will determine (based on the information in the routing table) the best interface for connecting to a given IP address.

---

The second question is: "How do I determine the MAC address of a given network adapter?"

The answer is [`GetAdaptersAddresses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915.aspx).  This function will return a linked-list of [`IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366058.aspx) structures.

From this, you should be able to look for the one with the `IfIndex` matching the one you want (likely the one from `GetBestInterace`). Alternatively, you can look at the `IfType` of each structure, and look specifically for any `IF_TYPE_ETHERNET_CSMACD` (ethernet) or `IF_TYPE_IEEE80211` (Wi-Fi) adapters.

---

The decision of which method exactly, you should use depends on what exactly, you're trying to accomplish.